# Exportar varios arrays a una tabla de excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

tengo 4 arrays de numpy de dimension (16,19) llamados X,Y,R,S. Representan mediciones de distintas variables de varias secciones de un cilindro (coordenadas X,Y, R-radio de la sección y S-altura a la que está la sección con respecto al suelo). Ya he obtenido todos esos valores y ahora quiero exportarlos en una tabla de excel para poder hacer cálculos con ellos.

He hecho una dibujo de lo que tengo y lo que quiero obtener por si alguien sabe qué comandos podría utilizar (lo adjunto). He probado a transponer mis arrays:

```
X_T=np.transpose(X)
Y_T=np.transpose(Y)
R_T=np.transpose(R)
S_T=np.transpose(S)
```

Y luego he intentado apilarlos usando distintas funciones pero creo que no estoy entendiendo bien lo que hacen porque ninguna me da lo que quiero.

```
pila=np.dstack((X_T,Y_T,R_T,S_T))
pila_v=np.vstack((X_T,Y_T,R_T,S_T))
pila_h=np.hstack((X_T,Y_T,R_T,S_T))
pila_conc=np.concatenate((X_T,Y_T,R_T,S_T))
```

Soy bastante nueva en Python por eso puede lo que estoy intentando hacer no tenga demasiado sentido. Agradecería mucho algo de orientación. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: mmm, si tu duda es como guardar tus datos a `excel`. Yo pasaría los datos a un `DataFrame`  y luego usaría `to_excel('C:/****/**.xlsx')`

Comment: A ver si adivino... ¿te serviría algo como esto? `df=pd.DataFrame({"X": X, "Y": Y, "R": R, "S": S})` (previamente necesitas `import pandas as pd`). Prueba a imprimir el valor de `df` y si es lo que buscas, lo puedes convertir a excel con `df.to_excel()`

Comment: He probado lo que me dices, pero no es exactamente lo que quiero.En el DataFrame, me salen las cuatro columnas X, Y, R y S, pero los valores en vez de ir hacia abajo uno en cada fila,  aparecen todos juntos en la misma celda, ¿sabes cómo puedo hacer que vayan hacia abajo? Gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

te pongo ejemplo con uno de los array, no sé si es exactamente lo que buscas. Un saludo

```html
from numpy.random import random
X=random((16, 9))
df_X=pd.DataFrame(X)
df_X
```